# What's the most efficient Darkmoon Faire activity?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

The new Darkmoon Faire introduces a variety of new activities, many of which provide Darkmoon Faire Prize Tickets, Darkmoon Faire reputation, or both. Which activities are the most profitable in either regard, for the amount of time and tokens you need to invest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From least time and tokens to most:

1. Purchasing the dungeon and PvP drops off the Auction House.  They're going for anywhere between 100-1000g on my realm's AH, but literally takes seconds to do and you get anywhere between 4 to 10 tickets per completion (each item has its own value in tickets.  These can be found on Wowhead).  Obviously not the most efficient for gold, but a winner for time and tokens.  These can only be completed once per week, so once per Faire.
2. The profession quests.  These reward five tokens per completion, if memory serves, and you should be able to do six (two primary professions and four secondary).  None took over five minutes to complete and most just require you to go to your capital to purchase the required items for a few copper.  These are also weekly, so once per Faire.
3. The daily quests.  At the rate of one ticket per daily quest, these reward five tickets in the same time it takes you to get more tickets from the other options.

Obviously your order will be different if you are gold limited, but for time and token investment that is the best order.